# CMakelist - if(DEFINED) syntax

Tags: c++, bash, unix, makefile, cmake

I was going through a CMakelist.txt file which has an entry for a C++ project containing a **src** and a **tests** folder.
I need to know what does the following syntax means?

```
if(DEFINED BUILD_TESTS)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif(DEFINED BUILD_TESTS)
```

Thanks 
rG

Answer (score 3):

You can always check a [manual](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax), though I think it's clear here:

```
if(DEFINED BUILD_TESTS)
```

checks if the variable BUILD_TESTS is defined in the environment. If so,:

```
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

`add_subdirectory` is a [built in function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html) (cmake has those) that adds a directory called tests (surprise) to the list of stuff needed to be built/compiled.

`BUILD_TESTS` itself is a CMAKE variable, and will determine if 'tests' will be a part of the Makefile. Thanks @Tsyvarev for pointing this out.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I dont know where ths "BUILD_TESTS" is defined. Thats the problem. I am going through a totally new project where I dont know a lot.

Comment: This checks the 'environment', as in you defined this before/during running `make`. This can be done in a configuration file, in the Makefile itself or by you in the shell. Otherwise the Makefile will assume you don't want to build the tests. Another option is to put `BUILD_TESTS=1` when running `make`. It not being defined is a perfectly viable option.

Comment: @kabanus: Expression `DEFINED BUILD_TESTS` checks only **CMake variables**, it doesn't look into *environment* ones.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for pointing that out, I missed that - and I'll amend. **So my previous comment is wrong**, if anyone reads this.